# Overwrite portions of some rows of a numpy array with portions of other rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array, for example:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 [11,12,13,14,15]
 [16,17,18,19,20]
 [21,22,23,24,25]
 [26,27,28,29,30]]
```

I want to overwrite portions of some rows with portions of other rows. For example I want to overwrite the 2nd and 3rd value of the 1st row with the 2nd and 3rd value of the 0th row. Rows can only be a "donor" or "recipient", not both.

The way I've set this up so far, I have a 1D array marking certain rows as "donors", e.g.

```
`donors = np.array([0,2])
```

and a 1D array marking certain rows as recipients, e.g.

```
`recips = np.array([1,3])
```

and an array specifying the positions to overwrite, e.g.

```
`positions_to_overwrite = np.array([2,3],[3,4]])
```

So what I'd want to happen here is that the 2nd and 3rd values (counting from zero) of row 1 are overwritten by the 2nd and 3rd values of row 0, and the 3rd and 4th values of row 3 are overwritten by the 3rd and 4th values of row 2. That would give me:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
 [6, 7, 3, 4, 10]
 [11,12,13,14,15]
 [16,17,18,14,15]
 [21,22,23,24,25]
 [26,27,28,29,30]]
```

Hope that makes sense. If the solution involves representing information about what should be transferred from one row to another in a different/better way, that's totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One approach** assuming `A` as the 2D input array -

```
A[recips[:,None],positions_to_overwrite] = A[donors[:,None],positions_to_overwrite]
```

**A bit of explanation:** Each row of `positions_to_overwrite` represents the column indices of `donors` and `recips`. Now, both `donors` and `recips` represent the row indices that are to be manipulated. So, we need to convert both `donors` and `recips` to column vectors, so that each element of them would correspond to each row of `positions_to_overwrite`. This is sort of like "broadcasting", but for indexing purposes.

Comment: Thanks! It was the '[:,None]' part that was missing from my attempts. That converts a 1D array to a 2D array with one column?

Comment: @BenS. Added few comments to help out.